# Remove from list after correct twice and stopwatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

I'm creating a quiz and I'm new to python so please go easy on me! Basically I am trying to create a stopwatch that will display the time taken AFTER the quiz has ended and not while it is still ongoing. I tried implementing a code using

```
import time
import os
s=0
m=0
h=0
while s<=60:
    os.system('cls')
    print (h, 'Hours',  m, 'Minutes', s, 'Seconds'
    time.sleep(1)
    if s ==60:
        m+=1
        s=0
    elif m == 60:
        h+=1
        m=0
        s=o
```

and it worked but it was continuously just telling the time and my quiz wouldn't even start. I want something that will just display the total time at the end. Any tips?

Furthermore, I have no idea where to start with this. I want to implement a piece of code where when the user matches the random word to the correct definition TWICE, I want that word to disappear (I'd like too keep the definition as 3 random definitions are listed.)

Here is where I extract my words -

```
h=0
for h in range (len(words)):
        if RandomKey == words [x]:
            position = x


Word = definitions[position]
```

Thanks for any suggestions given!

Comment: Tell us about that "etc, etc." part, we need to see the code to help you with it

Comment: please put your code.

Comment: Sorry about that @unixer

Comment: You should try getting each separate part of the code working independently before combining them. That is, get the timer working and then get your quiz working and it should be much more obvious how to get them to work together. To start you off: you never increment `s` so the function will loop infinitely.

Comment: You can use threads to do different tasks simultaneously in your one programm. One thread can do the quiz stuff and other one can keep the track of time. If you never heard of threads then please do visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919752/making-a-program-munltithreaded/22921132#22921132

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to keep track of the time as it is passing, record the time at the start, record again at the end, and subtract to get the time passed:

```
import time
start = time.time()
# do stuff
end = time.time()
duration_in_seconds = end - start
```